# Issue with compiled .jar when trying to open it outside of IDE

Tags: java, sqlite, maven, jdbc, sqlitejdbc

I've been building a small program with friends. We have been using JavaFX for the program and are too late to use OpenJFX, thus making us use JDK 1.8.0. We are using Maven to compile everything and compiles successfully.

The issue is that when we go to the folder of the `.jar`, when we try to open it with this line `java -jar Medical-Application.jar`, we get a No suitable driver found for `jdbc:sqlite:(my path to DB)`.

We already tried to add `Class.forName("org.sqlite.JDBC");` but it didn't work.

Here is the POM file.

```
<project xmlns="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0" xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
  xsi:schemaLocation="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0 http://maven.apache.org/xsd/maven-4.0.0.xsd">
  <modelVersion>4.0.0</modelVersion>

  <groupId>TP3.projet-session</groupId>
  <artifactId>medical-project</artifactId>
  <version>1.0-SNAPSHOT</version>
  <packaging>jar</packaging>

  <name>medical-project</name>
  <url>http://maven.apache.org</url>
  <developers>
    <developer>
        <id>aville</id>
        <name>ArnaudVillemaire</name>
        <email>villemaire.arnaud@gmail.com</email>
    </developer>
  </developers>
  <properties>
    <project.build.sourceEncoding>UTF-8</project.build.sourceEncoding>
    <javafx.version>2.2</javafx.version>
  </properties>
  <build>
        <plugins>
            <plugin>
                <!-- copy all dependencies of your app to target folder-->
                <groupId>org.apache.maven.plugins</groupId>
                <artifactId>maven-dependency-plugin</artifactId>
                <version>3.1.1</version>
                <executions>
                    <execution>
                        <id>copy-dependencies</id>
                        <phase>package</phase>
                        <configuration>
                            <overWriteReleases>false</overWriteReleases>
                            <overWriteSnapshots>false</overWriteSnapshots>
                            <overWriteIfNewer>true</overWriteIfNewer>
                        </configuration>
                        <goals>
                            <goal>copy-dependencies</goal>
                        </goals>
                    </execution>
                </executions>
            </plugin>
            <plugin>
                <groupId>org.apache.maven.plugins</groupId>
                <artifactId>maven-antrun-plugin</artifactId>
                <version>1.8</version>
                <executions>
                    <execution>
                        <phase>package</phase>
                        <configuration>
                            <target>
                                <!-- define the deploy ANT task-->
                                <taskdef name="jfxdeploy" classname="com.sun.javafx.tools.ant.DeployFXTask"
                                    classpathref="maven.plugin.classpath" />
                                <!-- define the JarSing ANT task-->
                                <taskdef name="jfxsignjar" classname="com.sun.javafx.tools.ant.FXSignJarTask"
                                    classpathref="maven.plugin.classpath" />
                                <jfxdeploy width="1024" height="768"
                                    outdir="${project.build.directory}/deploy" outfile="${project.build.finalName}"
                                    nativeBundles="all">
                                    <info title="${project.name}" />
                                    <!-- set the main class of your applcation; I had to create a Main.class (class Main extends MyMain) otherwise it will return an error on start-->
                                    <application name="${project.name}" mainClass="TP3.projet_session.App" />
                                    <resources>
                                        <fileset dir="${project.build.directory}" includes="*.jar" />
                                        <fileset dir="${project.build.directory}/dependency"
                                            includes="*.jar" />
                                    </resources>
                                    <!-- set your jvm args-->
                                    <platform javafx="${javafx.version}+">
                                        <jvmarg value="-Xms512m" />
                                        <jvmarg value="-Xmx1024m" />
                                    </platform>
                                </jfxdeploy>

                            </target>
                        </configuration>
                        <goals>
                            <goal>run</goal>
                        </goals>
                    </execution>
                </executions>
                <dependencies>
                    <dependency>
                        <groupId>com.oracle</groupId>
                        <artifactId>ant-javafx</artifactId>
                        <version>${javafx.version}</version>
                        <systemPath>${java.home}/../lib/ant-javafx.jar</systemPath>
                        <scope>system</scope>
                    </dependency>
                    <dependency>
                        <groupId>com.oracle</groupId>
                        <artifactId>javafx</artifactId>
                        <version>${javafx.version}</version>
                        <systemPath>${java.home}/lib/ext/jfxrt.jar</systemPath>
                        <scope>system</scope>
                    </dependency>
                </dependencies>
            </plugin>
        </plugins>
        <finalName>Medical-Application</finalName>
    </build>
  <dependencies>
    <dependency>
      <groupId>junit</groupId>
      <artifactId>junit</artifactId>
      <version>4.12</version>
      <scope>test</scope>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
      <groupId>com.oracle</groupId>
      <artifactId>javafx</artifactId>
      <version>${javafx.version}</version>
      <systemPath>${java.home}/lib/ext/jfxrt.jar</systemPath>
      <scope>system</scope>
    </dependency>
      <!-- https://mvnrepository.com/artifact/org.xerial/sqlite-jdbc -->
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.xerial</groupId>
        <artifactId>sqlite-jdbc</artifactId>
        <version>3.7.2</version>
    </dependency>

  </dependencies>
</project>
```

I've read that compiling with an IDE and Maven manages the classpath for the runtime too. Is there a way so we can run it properly when we try to open it with a command line?

Any ideas?

Comment: What is the content of the manifest of the jar (in `META-INF/MANIFEST.mf` in the jar file)?

Answer (score -1):

You need to include the JDBC driver in the classpath. When invoking java -jar Medical-Application.jar, the jvm looks in your current directory for the sqlite lib. You will need to do something like

java -cp path/to/sqlite.jar -jar Medical-Application.jar

This way java can find the correct location of the jdbc driver.

Comment: It still doesn't work. Now getting ClassNotFoundException.

Comment: `-cp` doesn't work in combination with `-jar`. When using `-jar`, the `META-INF/MANIFEST.mf` file in the JAR has to define the full classpath.